# How can I export my MS Access Data to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a MS Access database and I want to convert it to run on MS SQL Server.

How can I export it?

Comment: It's not clear if you have an Access application with Jet data tables and you want to upsize only the data tables to SQL Server or if you think that SQL Server upsizing will also convert your forms/reports/etc. to something else -- it will not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use SQL Server Integration Services to import into SQL Server (2005), rather than export.

Answer (score 2):

Tools.. Options... Upsizing Wizard, if I recall correctly.

Strictly speaking, you'll always need software to do it, unless you have 3 wishes from the ETL fairy.

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL Server is **SQL Server 2000** or **SQL Server 7**, [SQL Server Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) mentioned by [Miles D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3898/miles-d) was calles [Data Transformation Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917688.aspx). By the way: I love this tool. It's awesome.

If for some reason you can't (or don't want to) use any of these tools, you could always write a very short piece of code (in Java, C# or whatever you feel comfortable with) to accomplish the same thing for your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the free *[Microsoft SQL Migration Assistant for Access](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/migration.aspx)* (SSMA): it's purpose is to convert Access apps to SQL: it's great and it's free.

I wrote a blog post about it:
http://blog.nkadesign.com/2009/ms-access-upsizing-to-sql-server-2008/